# Non-convergence in nonlinear regression

Tags: nonlinear-regression, convergence

I've been studying a manuscript from the chemistry literature (not mine) that resorted to a trick to obtain convergence of a non-linear model fitted to experimental data. They wanted to estimate a total of 5 parameters (a1-a5), but the model wouldn't converge. So they estimated a1-a4 (with a5=0), then held a3 constant at the value just obtained while estimating a1-a2 and a4-a5. Then they re-estimated a1-a4 with a5 constant at the value just obtained. And once again fitted a1-a2 and a4-a5. They used this process using the same model for 9 different data sets and reported the averages and standard deviations for the 3 parameters of real interest (a3,a4, and a5), which should be the same regardless of dataset. The data analysis tool they are using doesn't permit all 9 datasets to be combined and analyzed together. In any case, the results are supported by independent evidence that the parameters are consistent with values of parameters for related reactions.

As I understand it, there can be 2 causes for non-convergence: poor initial guesses and under-constrained model (data truly don’t allow all parameters to be estimated). The process they use should help get past bad initial guesses, but not an under-constrained model. If bad initial guesses were the cause, I’d think once the iterative process “converges” they should have been able to use those estimates as initial guesses and obtained convergence with all parameters estimated simultaneously.

Would that be considered a legitimate approach to handling lack of convergence? I would think that without the last step, the iterative process described would not be recommended.

In the case of an under-constrained model, convergence would never be obtained with a single curve, but there may have been enough information in all 9 curves together to make it work. I would have liked to have seen a simultaneous fit to all the curves, but in the absence of the proper tool, it seems like what they did was decent.

So, what I'm asking is whether the conclusions that I reached about the aforementioned data analysis are correct. Responses will be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of convergence are we talking about? Is this about numerical behavior of the fitting algorithm (e.g. convergence to local minimum vs. global minimum vs. stalling/exploding), or about the meaning of the outputs (e.g. a good/physically meaningful/correct output was obtained or not).

Comment: Not all nonlinear optimization and nonlinear least squares software is equally robust.  Some is pretty damn robust (although initial values may still matter), and some "blows" (to use a readily understood but not very technical term).. As well, of the decent software, there are often a number of algorithmic parameters which can be adjusted and change the behavior of the software, and there may be options on finite difference vs. exact derivatives, etc. Anyhow, we don't have nearly enough information to make a concrete assessment of matters in this case. Nonlinear is trickier than linear.

Comment: I am only reading a manuscript, so I'm not 100% sure. They state that "the model used...was under-constrained and the three...constants [a3-a5 in my description] could not be determined simultaneously." I'm not sure how they could tell if the data were really inadequate or if their initial guesses weren't so good.

The software they used is reasonably well regarded in the field, but isn't anywhere nearly universally accepted. It uses Newton-Raphson to solve a non-linear system of equations and then some other method, L-M most likely, to optimize the parameters.

Comment: Given the lack of specifics, I should clarify what I'm asking. More generally, under what circumstances would you consider the process that I described above to be valid? 
1) When the final estimates obtained can be used as initial guesses and the software then converges for individual curves?
2) If 1) doesn't hold, but the variability in the most poorly constrained parameter (a5) observed upon fitting multiple curves is reasonably small? (Implies that such a result is not acceptable for non-convergence with only one curve).
3) Only if validated by a simultaneous fit of all 9 curves?

Comment: Newton-Raphson could be anywhere from robust to junk, depending on the implementation. That doesn't tell you much.  And for all we know, there could be outright errors in the user inputs to the code. BTW, some software could work fine for certain models, data, and initial values, and be a disaster for others.

Comment: I think the honest answer is that without: (1) their specific problem (2) their specific data and (3) their specific code, it's nearly impossible to say wtf is going on. So many things could be f'ed: bad line search algorithm, numerical issues, stuck on a plateau...

Just for starters, is the optimization problem convex? Are they doing maximum likelihood on something like a log concave likelihood function? With modern techniques, convex vs. non-convex is a far more important distinction than between linear vs. non-linear. If it's non-convex, could get stuck on saddlepoint, local optimum...

Comment: Another point... if the problem is convex and you're worried, you can generally verify that an answer is optimal, verify it outside of the optimization software. (Check gradient is zero of if constrained problem, use calculated values of multipliers to check that strong duality holds.)

Comment: @Matthew Gunn Re: "bad line search algorithm".   Might be no line search (or trust region) algorithm, which yeah, is a bad line search algorithm.

Comment: You should edit your question to cite the manuscript.

Comment: Sorry, but I'll have to wait on putting up all the details and citation. Now that I see the way these discussions go, I think I'll start a new question on a closely related subject.